# Splitting a string with different delimiters

Tags: c++, string, split, io, stl

Having the following type of input:

```
add name, breed, birthDate, vaccinationsCount, photograph
```

(e.g. `add boo, yorkshire terrier, 01-13-2017, 7, boo puppy.jpg`)

I want to split this string to get my parameters out of it and it didn't work.

My code looked like this:

```cpp
getline(cin, listOfCommands);
string functionToApply = listOfCommands.substr(0, listOfCommands.find(" "));
int position = listOfCommands.find(" ");
listOfCommands.erase(0, position + 1);
cout << listOfCommands;
if (functionToApply == "exit")
    break;
else if (functionToApply == "add")
{
    position = listOfCommands.find(", ");
    string name = listOfCommands.substr(0, position);
    listOfCommands.erase(0, position + 1);
    position = listOfCommands.find(", ");
    string breed = listOfCommands.substr(0, position);
    listOfCommands.erase(0, position + 2);
    position = listOfCommands.find(", ");
    string birthDate = listOfCommands.substr(0, position);
    listOfCommands.erase(0, position + 2);
    position = listOfCommands.find(", ");
    string nrShorts = listOfCommands.substr(0, position);
    listOfCommands.erase(0, position + 2);
    string photo = listOfCommands;
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but if after the first `find` you call `listOfCommands.find(", ", position+2)` you won't have to waste time erasing the part you've already scanned.

Comment: Only thing I see there that'll cause you any grief is `listOfCommands.erase(0, position + 1);` is different from all the others. Looks like you'll get an extra space in the front of `breed`.

Comment: Quick hack demo: https://ideone.com/K68HnS Other than that one space, looks good to me.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

For this sample I'm using [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with custom delimiter, [std::stringstream](https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to help parse the inputed stream and [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to store the parameters, (if you prefer you can assign them to the variables you created for them):

[**Live sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iMp5uUEeLj7qoNtq)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::string listOfCommands, temp, command;
    std::vector<std::string> args; //container for the arguments

    //retrieve command
    getline(std::cin, command, ' ');

    if (command == "add") {

        getline(std::cin, listOfCommands);     
        std::stringstream ss(listOfCommands);

        while (getline(ss, temp, ',')) { //parse comma separated arguments

            while (*(temp.begin()) == ' ')
                temp.erase(temp.begin()); //remove leading blankspaces

            args.push_back(temp); // add parameter to container
        }

        //test print
        for (std::string str : args){
            std::cout << str << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
add boo, yorkshire terrier, 01-13-2017, 7,    boo puppy.jpg
```

Output:

```
boo
yorkshire terrier
01-13-2017
7
boo puppy.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [regex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator):

```
#include <regex>

const int split_constant = -1;
std::vector<std::string> args(
  std::sregex_token_iterator(listOfCommands.begin(), 
                             listOfCommands.end(), 
                             std::regex(", "), 
                             split_constant),
  std::sregex_token_iterator());
```

Of course you don't have to save the tokens in a vector, you can also just iterate over them:

```
auto iter = std::sregex_token_iterator(listOfCommands.begin(), 
                                       listOfCommands.end(), 
                                       std::regex(", "), 
                                       split_constant);
const string functionToApply = *iter++;
if (functionToApply == "exit") break;
const string name  = *iter++;
const string breed = *iter++;
// etc.
```

Comment: Why not use std::regex_token_iterator?